# Convert Clock column postgresql to date and hour

Tags: postgresql, date, time

friends.

How can I convert zabbix clock from trends table to date and hour?

I did this command on postgresql.

```
select clock, value_min from trends limit 1;
```

I have this return:

```
clock       value_min

1409767200  -42
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + interval '1409767200 second';
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/2938)**

or you can try this:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1409767200) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/2939)**

Answer (score 0):

I format the output with:

```
to_char(to_timestamp(t.clock), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS')
```

like this:

```
   SELECT t.clock, to_char(to_timestamp(t.clock), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS'), t.*
     FROM trends t 
    WHERE t.clock >= extract(epoch from date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp(2)))::int
    ORDER BY t.clock desc 
    --limit 10 
    ;
```